# BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading Clp.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: java, linear-programming, clp

I am using `clp-java for linear optimization, but when I try to run the code, I get the following error:
The process keeps running and the following keeps getting printed repeatedly.

> BridJ: LoadLibrary error when loading C:\Users\Abhijay\AppData\Local\Temp\CLPExtractedLib1623275631902676\Clp.dll : A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

I have added the following dependencies in the pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.quantego</groupId>
    <artifactId>clp-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nativelibs4java</groupId>
    <artifactId>bridj</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my code:

```
import com.quantego.clp.CLP;
import com.quantego.clp.CLP.ALGORITHM;
import com.quantego.clp.CLPVariable;

public class ClpDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLP model = new CLP().algorithm(ALGORITHM.AUTO).maximization().presolve(false);
        CLPVariable x1 = model.addVariable().lb(0);
        CLPVariable x2 = model.addVariable().lb(0);
        model.createExpression().add(10, x1).add(20, x2).leq(120);
        model.createExpression().add(8, x1).add(8, x2).leq(80);
        model.createExpression().add(12, x1).add(16, x2).asObjective();
        model.solve();
        double x1Value = model.getSolution(x1);
        double x2Value = model.getSolution(x2);
        System.out.println("x1 :" + x1Value + " x2 :" + x2Value);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest build from the dev branch solves the problem. It'll be pushed to maven soon.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my own version of linear programming, also supports mixed integer linear programming.
If you are interested in using the tool, here is the [link](https://github.com/DiegoCatalano/Catalano-Framework).

Problem:

```
max: x+y
-2x + 2y >= 1
-8x + 10y <= 13
x,y : real
```

**Example of Linear Programming.**

```
    //Function
    double[] function = new double[] {1,1};

    //Constraints
    List<Constraint> constraints = new ArrayList<>();
    constraints.add(new Constraint(new double[] {-2,2}, Constraint.Symbol.GREATER_THAN, 1));
    constraints.add(new Constraint(new double[] {-8,10}, Constraint.Symbol.LESS_THAN, 13));

    LinearProgramming lp = new LinearProgramming(LinearProgramming.Objective.Maximize);

    int status = lp.Solve(function, constraints);
    switch(status){
        case LinearProgramming.INFEASIBLE:
            System.out.println("Infeasible solution");
        break;
        case LinearProgramming.OPTIMAL:
            System.out.println("Optimal solution found");
        case LinearProgramming.UNBOUNDED:
            System.out.println("Unbounded solution");
    }

    double[] coef = lp.getCoefficients();
    double solution = lp.getSolution();
```

Problem:

```
max: x+y
-2x + 2y >= 1
-8x + 10y <= 13
x: real
y: integer
```

**Example of Mixed Integer Linear Programming.**

```
    //Function
    double[] function = new double[] {1,1};

    //Constraints
    List<Constraint> constraints = new ArrayList<>();
    constraints.add(new Constraint(new double[] {-2,2}, Constraint.Symbol.GREATER_THAN, 1));
    constraints.add(new Constraint(new double[] {-8,10}, Constraint.Symbol.LESS_THAN, 13));

    //Define integer variables
    //1: integer
    //0: double
    int[] types = new int[] {0,1};

    MixedIntegerLinearProgramming lp = new MixedIntegerLinearProgramming(MixedIntegerLinearProgramming.Objective.Maximize);
    lp.setType(types);

    int status = lp.Solve(function, constraints);
    switch(status){
        case LinearProgramming.INFEASIBLE:
            System.out.println("Infeasible solution");
        break;
        case LinearProgramming.OPTIMAL:
            System.out.println("Optimal solution found");
        case LinearProgramming.UNBOUNDED:
            System.out.println("Unbounded solution");
    }

    double[] coef = lp.getCoefficients();
    double solution = lp.getSolution();
```